# How to parse embed.FS templates with the template.ParseFS function

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to parse all of the templates in the same `template.Template` struct but I don't know how and also it gives me an error. I have the next code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

//go:embed internal/web/views/*
var viewsFS embed.FS

func main() {
    tmpls, err := template.New("").ParseFS(viewsFS, "**/*.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // Debugging I finded out that the error is here so the code below is irrelevant
    }
    tmpls.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "pages/home", nil)
}
```

The error that gives me the `ParseFS` method is the next:

```bash
$ 2023/09/16 23:36:42 template: pattern matches no files: `**/*.html`
```

I think that the error is in the `patterns` parameter of the `ParseFS` method I don't know.

I have many html files inside of the `internal/web/views` directory, in fact all of the files inside that folder are html files, each one having one or more `{{define}}`-type templates.

I will appreciate any help thank you

Comment: thank you, but how do I do that? may you write the answer and if it's good mark it as the answer of the question?

Comment: this only selects the files that are inside of the `views` folder, for example this doesn't match: `path.Match("/internal/views/*.html", "/internal/views/another-folder/abc.html")` but this does it: `path.Match("/internal/views/*.html", "/internal/views/abc.html")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Charlie-Tumahai credits to him for this [documentation (Official Go Package website)](https://pkg.go.dev/path#Match) about Glob patterns in Go

So in order to parse all of my templates in the same `template.Template` struct I had to do the next:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

//go:embed internal/web/views/*
var viewsFS embed.FS

func main() {
    tmpls, err := template.New("").
        ParseFS(viewsFS,
            "internal/web/views/*/*.html",
            "internal/web/views/*/*/*.html",
            /* Add more `*` if you have templates that are more nested */
        )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tmpls.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "pages/home", nil)
}
```

What I did was research more about Glob patterns and learn how to use it in Go, Glob patterns in Go are made in a different way that in any other language.